# Webpack: require('index.html') vs just copying index.html

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I'm fairly new to webpack.

From a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/y_RFOaSDL8I) (Academind) I watched, the guy teaches the user to include the HTML file in the entry .js file. From what I understand, webpack will then use HtmlWebpackPlugin to extract the `require`d HTML file out, then inject either as a file or code into that HTML file. Is my understanding correct?

I'd like the above question answered, but that's not the main question. The main question is the reason for going through such pain.

Can't I just have the .html files copied to `/dist` and have each .html file have `bundle1.js`, `bundle2.js`, etc., in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial required html file because it was thought that it was easier to let webpack (HtmlWebpackPlugin) insert all the script tags for the bundles automatically, without having to do that manually.

You can also not require that, and add the `template` property on `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. That will do the same thing.

You can also copy to dist, of course. But that would require you to insert manually script tags on your html. That starts to get worst when you have hashes on your filenames.